# Harmonic function and Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Consider the following theorem:

> Assume $\varOmega\subset\mathbb{R}^{N} $ is an open region.
> Let $ u:\varOmega \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function. We say that $ u $ is harmonic in the weak way, if for any  $ \delta(x) : \varOmega \to \mathbb{R} $ with compact support, twice continuously differentiable, the following holds

> $$ \intop_{\varOmega}u\left(x\right)\varDelta\delta\left(x\right)dx=0 $$

> We know that any weak harmonic function is also an harmonic function (in the regular way) in the same region.

Based on this theorem, given a region $ \varOmega=G\times\left(-\rho,\rho\right) $ where $\rho $ is a positive real number, and G is also an open region, and given a function $ u\left(x_{1},...,x_{N}\right):\overline{\varOmega}\to\mathbb{R} $ such that $ u $ is twice continuously differentiable and harmonic on $ \varOmega^{+}=G\times\left(0,\rho\right)$, and also for any $ x\in\varOmega $ we have the following:
$ u\left(x_{1},...,x_{N-1},-x_{N}\right)=-u\left(x_{1},...,x_{N-1},x_{N}\right) $

How can I prove that $ u $ is harmonic on $ \varOmega $ ?

Comment: What have you checked so far? Is it harmonic in $G \times (-\rho,0)$? Is it continuous in $\Omega$?

Comment: Sorry, it seemed ovious. Yes, the funcion is twice continuously in the region you mentioned and also harmonic. But I cant see how to generlize it to the whole region

Comment: Yes, the point is that one should describe his/her attempts and difficulties. Otherwise the question is likely to be ignored, or even closed.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I agree. Usually I do describe my attempts, but this time I really didnt know where to start (except the obvious, but the obvious didnt really seem related to me, so I prefered to start from scretch)

Comment: Ah, I understand. I don't know how to fill in the details, but given the "obvious things", one can look at the definition by dividing the integral into domains $G \times (-\rho,0)$ and $G \times (\rho,0)$.